# How to add custom attrs in framework to let app use?

Tags: android, frameworks

I want to add some custom attributes in Android framework like the original attrs "windowIsFloating",so our App developers can use the custom attrs to implement special features on our own device .
I added the custom attrs `<attr name="customOperation1" format="reference" /` in frameworks/base/core/res/res/values/attrs.xml and public.xml ,also the framework compile is OK.
But when App used classes.jar in Android Studio project to refer to "customOperation1" through below way `<item name="android:customOperation1">@drawable/decor_maximize_button_light</item>` ,there's error when compile in Android Studio. The error is "style attribute 'android:attr/customOperation1' not found" .
Are there any solutions?

I want our App developers can use my framework custom attrs in their App theme.